# Remove "%" from strings in serialized arrays in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wordpress, serialization

In the course of converting a blog from Blogger to WP and running a script to grab hot-linked images for hosting, I ended up with some funky images names like

> act%252Bapandas-210x290.png

These image names prevent the image from displaying on a webpage, due the url encoding ending up in the file name itself (don't ask!). I renamed them on the file server, no prob, but the names are also in the attachment metadata for each post.

How can I remove the "%" from all the image references in the  `wp_postmeta` table? Most of them occur in **serialized arrays** in `meta_value`s for the `meta_key`s of `_wp_attachment_metadata`. I've had no luck finding a plugin, and am unsure how to institute a pure SQL solution.

**EDIT:**

As the commentators have said, the issue is *changing or removing* the "%" character AND updating the array so it reports the correct number of characters (ie the s:13 would indicate yoursite.com is 13 char[])  **I'm also open to using a php solution**! Whatever can help me fix this mess.

**AFTERNOTE AND SOLUTION**

I didn't really frame this question in terms of WordPress issue, I framed it as a SQL problem. I awarded my answer accordingly. But I was able to solve the problem natively (with help from [Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13560/remove-from-strings-in-serialized-arrays-in-wp-postmeta/13561#13561) @.Here is how I solved the problem, using native WordPress functions inside the loop:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1, ));

foreach( $posts as $post ) {

    // retrieve data, unserialized automatically
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_wp_attachment_metadata', true);

    // loop through array to do any search and replaces

    // write it back
    update_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_attachment_metadata', $meta); }
```

These functions will automatically determine type of data you are retrieving or writing and (un)serialize it if necessary. This is handled by internal use of maybe_serialize() and maybe_unserialize() functions.

Comment: Please see @zerkms's comments for pitfalls in changing serialized array data.

Comment: that's why it is advised not to store data in serialized arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure it is not possible to do with pure SQL due to complexity of serialized array structure.

Comment: Sorry, should have framed the question to say that I'm open to any solution really.

Comment: @two7s_clash: exactly. It is impossible ;-)

Comment: would it not be possible to use a solution like this, working in some regex for $old and $new? If I'm misunderstanding, I'm happy to award you the answer.

Comment: @two7s_clash: the only possible way to change serialized array: 1) unserialize it 2) modify it 3) serialize it back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query: (replace the FIELD_NAMES with your field names entering them in as separate queries)

```
update wp_postmeta set FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, '%', '');
```

NOTE: You can change the '' and make it a space or whatever you want (leaving it as it replaces % with no space and nothing else).

**EDIT**: Nevermind, read the larger comment by Stephen Chung.

Comment: Do you know what the serialized array is?

Comment: @zerkms - I've added an example of the array in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of %'s, it is simple -- just replace '%' with something else with the `REPLACE` function.

However, I suspect you don't want this.  It is not clear in your question, but I suspect that you'll want to *decode* that %xxx back to the correct character as well.  In this case, you can first extract the "xxx" part of the string (which should be in hex) attach "0x" in front of it and cast it back to a number, then convert that number into string.  You then use SUBSTRING to stitch back your text data, with the "%" removed and the new string substituted in-place.

**EDIT: DO NOT DO THIS: THIS MAY BREAK THE SERIALIZED ARRAY (SEE COMMENT BELOW)**

I'm keeping this (incorrect) answer just so that people will know its pitfalls.

Comment: @zerkms, I think you have a point.  However, the way you make your point has something to be desired.  You should have put more information in your comments so that people can learn something.

Comment: @Stephen Chung: Ok. Serialized array is a special complex format that strongly relies on the data size. If you just remove something from the string without recalculation of sizes - you'll get your data broken. Here is a sample: http://ideone.com/2kFdy. In second case we simply removed `%` char and left the string size = 2 as is.

Comment: @zerkms, I'd assumed that in PHP serialized arrays, the '%' character is left alone (although I have not tested it).  If you think some '%' characters are used by PHP's serialization, please enlighten us.  If you believe that we should be converting %-escaped characters into the PHP-serialization format first, then please also enlighten us.

Comment: @zerkms, OK.  Got it.  Strange, but true.  Learn something new every day!  +1 to your comment.

Comment: @Stephen Chung: the only correct way to modify the data inside the serialized array is: 1) unserialize a string back into array 2) perform changes to the array items 3) serialize the array back to the string

Comment: @zerkms, in your test example, if you try `var_dump(unserialize('a:1:{s:1:"a";s:1:"b";}'));` (notice I changed the length of the second string to one), does it work?

Comment: @Stephen Chung: sure it does http://ideone.com/IanGl. But it could be tricky to recalculate manually ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the % signs in a column, you should be able to do something like:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET field_name = replace(field_name, '[%]', '')
```

Comment: Do you know what the serialized array is?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the problem, using native WordPress functions inside the loop:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1, ));

foreach( $posts as $post ) {

    // retrieve data, unserialized automatically
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_wp_attachment_metadata', true);

    // loop through array to do any search and replaces

    // write it back
    update_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_attachment_metadata', $meta); }
```